# issue with jquery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing jquery promises and something strange is happening in my demo code. What my code does is when I click on button then it receives a simple json data from the server. I am using two jquery promises one is `done()` and second is `fail()`. Whne I click on button it  receives data from the server but the `done()` is not executing the data is shown in the console via `fail()`. Why and how can I solve this? Following is my code

jquery

```
        var Obj = function () {
            return {
                gets: function (successHandler, errorHandler) {
                    console.log('hello');
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: '/server.php',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        type: 'GET'
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        $('.button').on('click', function () {
            var obj = new Obj();
            var promise = obj.gets();

            promise.done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

            promise.fail(function (e) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e)); //this logs below
            });
```

output

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<?php\n$response = array('oranges', 'apples', 'berries');\nexit(json_decode($response));","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

here is my php code

```
$response = array('oranges', 'apples', 'berries');
exit(json_decode($response));
```

Comment: Your server doesn't seem to be parsing `server.php` as a PHP file. You're getting raw PHP code in the `responseText`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $.ajax({
   url: '/server.php'
   dataType: 'JSON',
   ...
```

BUT

```
"responseText":"<?php\n$response = array ...
```

jQuery expects `JSON` but the server delivers the `PHP` source. So an parsing exception is thrown, the `Deferred` is rejected and `.fail()` is called.

Comment: Configure your server so that it runs `PHP` code. If you can't get it running then that would be another question with a `PHP` tag ;)